# How to rewrite domain in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am writing a user registration form.
After the user registers with a username e.g. "Billy", I would like him to use the url billy.mydomain.com to access the server.

The Zend framework link of billy.mydomain.com is
www.mydomain.com/profile/index/username/billy

I would like to know how I can rewrite the url from
www.mydomain.com/profile/index/username/billy
to
billy.mydomain.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throwing away my initial answer, [This Solution](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.hostname) is much more elegant.

```
$hostnameRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    ':username.mydomain.com',
    array(
        'controller' => 'profile',
    )
);

$pathRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(":action/*", array( 'action'=>'index' ));
$chain = $hostnameRoute->chain($pathRoute);

// add $chain to your router
```